# Subsetting data by condition

Tags: r, split, subset, plyr

I am trying to reshape/ reduce my data. So far, I employ a `for` loop (very slow) but from what I perceive, this should be quite fast with `Plyr`.

I have many groups (firms, as a factor in the dataset) and I want to drop entirely every firm which shows a 0 entry for `value` in any of that firm's cells. I thus create a new `data.frame` but leave out all groups showing 0 for `value` at some point.

The `for`loop:

```
Data Creation:

set.seed(1) 
mydf <- data.frame(firmname = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 40, replace = TRUE), 
        value = rpois(40, 2))

-----------------------------
splitby = mydf$firmname


new.data <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:(length(unique(splitby)))) {
temp <- subset(mydf, splitby == as.character(paste(unique(splitby)[i]))) 
    if (all(temp$value > 0) == "TRUE") {     
    new.data <- rbind(new.data, temp) 
} 
} 

Delete all empty firm factors 
new.data$splitby <- factor(new.data$splitby)
```

Is there a way to achieve that with the `plyr` package? Can the `subset` function be used in that context?

**EDIT**: *For the purpose of the reproduction of the problem, data creation, as suggested by BenBarnes, is added. Ben, thanks a lot for that. Furthermore, my code is altered so as to comply with the answers provided below.*

Comment: You don't provide sample data, but this sounds like a standard subset using the `[` operator.

Comment: @Andrie it sounds to me like he wants to drop all entries in a group in which any entry meets some condition.  So `plyr` or `by` seem easier.  Jan, please read this as it will help us solve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! I edited the post and added data reproduction as suggested by Ben (see below).

Comment: @Andrie: thanks a lot! The standard subset is actually what I need. Computationally, my for loop needs 122 seconds with my small test data set (~55k observations) , Plyr 17 seconds and the [] operation only 0.07!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could supply an anonymous function to the `.fun` argument in `ddply()`:

```
set.seed(1)

mydf <- data.frame(firmname = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 40, replace = TRUE),
  value = rpois(40, 2))

library(plyr)

ddply(mydf,.(firmname), function(x) if(any(x$value==0)) NULL else x )
```

Or using `[`, as suggested by Andrie:

```
firms0 <- unique(mydf$firmname[which(mydf$value == 0)])

mydf[-which(mydf$firmname %in% firms0), ]
```

Note that the results of `ddply` are sorted according to `firmname`

**EDIT**

For the example in your comments, this approach is again faster than using `ddply()` to subset, selecting only firms with more than three entries:

```
firmTable <- table(mydf$firmname)

firmsGT3 <- names(firmTable)[firmTable > 3]

mydf[mydf$firmname %in% firmsGT3, ]
```

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for these great answers! It is exactly what I was looking for. I was not aware of how to apply the 2nd version (the [ operation) on entire groups. As written in a comment further above, the [ operation is much faster than the Plyr or the for loop.

Comment: The 2nd answer works nice when conditioning on single cell values. Would it also work when conditioning on number of rows? I tried Plyr: `mydf <- ddply(mydf,.(firmname), function(x) if(length(x$firmname < 3 )) NULL else x )` and many other approaches with the `[` approach but can't get it to work.

Comment: I got it to work! `ddply(mydf, .(firmname), function(x) if(length(x$firmname) > 3) NULL else x )` is doing the job. This selects all groups (firms) with more than 3 observations. With `<` this data is sorted out. I guess it was only one `)` too much.

Comment: @Jan, thanks for the interesting additional question, and nice job solving it! I've edited my answer to include an alternative solution that seems to be faster than your solution using `ddply()`.